# Is the map $F: V \mapsto \text{End}(V)$ a functor?

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory

Suppose we are in the category $\mathcal{C}$ of (finite dimensional if necessary) vector spaces over a fixed field. My question then is, is the map $F$ which takes a vector space $V$ and returns it's endomorphism ring $\text{End}(V)=\text{Hom}(V,V)$ a functor?

For $F$ to be a functor, it needs to act on objects and morphisms in a compatible manner. It is clear what it sends each object to, but I can't seem to figure out what it might send each morphism to.

Consider a morphism $T: V \to W$. Then we need $F(T):\text{End}(V) \to \text{End}(W)$. If we were able to ensure that $T$ is invertible, there seem to be the natural choice of:
$$ F(T)(\phi) = T^{-1} \circ \phi \circ T$$

But as it stands, $T$ need not be invertible. I am getting the feeling that maybe there is no such natural choice which makes $F$ a functor, in which case, I am wondering, is that an actual theorem?

Comment: It is a functor, you just have to use the subcategory of vector spaces with invertible linear maps.

Comment: @arctictern the problem with that is that I am working with tensor categories, and in tensor categories you have that $\text{Hom}(V,W)$ is naturally a vector space and thus must be additive, however if you add two invertible linear transformations you need not get another.

Comment: Well, $\hom(V,W)$ is a bifunctor ${\rm Vect}^{\rm op}\times{\rm Vect}\to{\rm Vect}$. When specializing to $\hom(V,V)$, we have $V$ doing double duty as an object in two (inequivalent) categories, so it's not going to be a functor that way. Restricting to a subcategory with invertible maps is the only way, since that naturally reflects the nature of changing coordinates. Note that ${\rm End}(V)$ itself still includes all linear maps and is still a vector space.

Comment: @arctictern Thanks. The context of this question is really that I was wondering if there was a natural way to express that the mapping $\text{End}(V) \times V \to V$ defined by $(\phi, v) \mapsto \phi(v)$ is a natural (bilinear) mapping. My thought for doing this is that maybe I could construct a natural transformation from the functor $F(V) = \text{End}(V) \otimes V$ to the function $G(V)=V$. But it appears that the former isn't even a functor. Do you know of any way I could formalize what I was saying?

Comment: Yeah, $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)\otimes V\to V$ is a [dinatural transformation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dinatural+transformation).

Comment: You can view ${\rm End}(V)\otimes V$ as an endofunctor of the category of vector spaces with invertible linear maps, in which case the obvious maps ${\rm End}(V)\otimes V\to V$ form a natural transformation.

Comment: Also if $\mathcal C$ were the category of inner-product spaces then $F$ could be a functor by $F(T)(\phi)=T\phi T^\dagger$. So $F$ can definitely be made into a functor by picking an arbitrary inner product (or more generally non-degenerate bilinear form) on each object and then using the same construction. But this is unnatural.

Comment: @OscarCunningham can you please clarify how $\text{End}(V,V) \otimes V \to V$ is a dinatural transformation/what that means? I've looked at the definitions but it isn't really clear to me what that is supposed to mean.